# How to align a table and a div on the same line?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to align a table of 6 rows occupying 75% of the horizontal space next to a div with text that is to the right.

However, the following html code leads to them being on top of one another.

I tried to play with inline-block etc but no matter what I do it's not placing the block next to it.

What am I doing wrong? The entire working snippet is below:

```html
<div id="ResultDetails" style="border:solid; border-width:2px; overflow:auto; border-color:lightgray; padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px; padding-top:12px;padding-bottom: 12px;margin:10px">
<table style="width:80%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; ">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:large; color:midnightblue; text-align:left"><b>RESULT DETAILS</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:18%; font-size:large; padding-left: 2px"><i>Condition tested<sup>1</sup></i></td>
        <td style="width:20%; font-size:large; padding-left: 6px"><i>Result</i></td>
        <td style="width:20%; font-size:large; padding-left: 6px"><i>Risk Before Test<sup>2</sup></i></td>
        <td style="width:20%; font-size:large; padding-left: 6px"><i>Vehicle Risk Score<sup>3</sup></i></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:20%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; border-left: dashed">
    <tr> </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center">Positive Performance Stats </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center"> Cars: 91% </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center"> Buses: 93% </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center">Planes: 38% </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center">Minivans: 50% </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.
            Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you float the table to the left you get close to what you want. You will also need to deal with the border you've placed on the div since it adds width to the div. You can either tell the browser to include the border in the width calculation or remove the border.

E.g.

```
table {
    float : left;
}

#PPV {
    box-sizing : border-box;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/769k6zmd/2/

If the table is taller than the div to the right you'll need to add `overflow:auto` to the parent div because the floated table will overflow the parent div.

Information on `box-sizing`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: This one looks identical to what I see (even in JSfiddle its showing on top of each other)

Comment: @user3079275 Try removing the dashed border. Works in the latest Chrome/IE/Firefox.

Comment: @user3079275 Actually, if your browser isn't wide enough the table will be wider than its `width` property because there is no overflow clipping setup. This will push the div below it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try not making a `div` inside a `div`, but change the `divs` to `li` and have them not be inside each other. Like so

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li id="ResultDetails" style="display: inline-block; border:solid; border-width:2px;  border-color:lightgray; padding-left:12px;padding-right:12px; padding-top:12px;padding-bottom: 12px;margin:0px">
      <table style="width:75%">
        <tr>
          <td style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:large;     color:midnightblue; text-align:left"><b>RESULT DETAILS</b>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:25%; font-size:large; padding-left: 2px"><i>Condition tested<sup>1</sup></i>
          </td>
          <td style="width:25%; font-size:large; padding-left: 6px"><i>Result</i>
          </td>
          <td style="width:25%; font-size:large; padding-left: 6px"><i>Risk Before Test<sup>2</sup></i>
          </td>
          <td style="width:25%; font-size:large; padding-left: 6px"><i>Vehicle Risk Score<sup>3</sup></i>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
          <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </li>
    <li id="PPV" style="width:25%; border-left: dashed; display: inline-block; align-content: center;">
      Positive Performance Stats
      <br>Cars: 91%
      <br>Buses: 93%
      <br>Planes: 38%
      <br>Minivans: 50%
      <br>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the table inside a div(say div1) and set the width if the div to 75% and the width if the table to 100%. For the div(say div2) which needs to float to right side of the div1 set the width less than 25% because the padding given to outer div. for both div1 and div2 set float property to left.
You can see the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ResultDetails" style="border:solid;border-width: 2px;border-color:lightgray;padding-left: 1%;padding-right: 1%;padding-top: 1%;padding-bottom: 1%;margin: 1%;float: left;width: 96%;">
   <div style="
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
"><table style="width:100%;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="font-family:Calibri; font-size:large; color:midnightblue; text-align:left"><b>RESULT DETAILS</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:25%; font-size:large; padding-left: 2px"><i>Condition tested<sup>1</sup></i></td>
        <td style="width:25%; font-size:large; padding-left: 6px"><i>Result</i></td>
        <td style="width:25%; font-size:large; padding-left: 6px"><i>Risk Before Test<sup>2</sup></i></td>
        <td style="width:25%; font-size:large; padding-left: 6px"><i>Vehicle Risk Score<sup>3</sup></i></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_result}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_testing}}</td>
        <td class="BorderBottom">{{vehicle_pollution}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table></div>
<div id="PPV" style="width: 24%;border-left: dashed;display: inline-block;align-content: center;float: left;">
    Positive Performance Stats <br>
    Cars: 91% <br>
    Buses: 93%<br>
    Planes: 38%<br>
    Minivans: 50%<br>
    Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
</div>
</div>


</body></html>
```